# BibLaTeX: Difference between @Online and @WWW

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

As the title of this question already reveals: What is the difference between the `@Online` and `@WWW` literature type in BibLaTeX?

Comment: Documentation clearly says that `www` is "An alias for `@online`, provided for `jurabib` compatibility."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the `biblatex` documentation on page 13, §2.1.2 *Type Aliases*,

> [`@www` is] An alias for `@online`, provided for `jurabib` compatibility.

In Appendix A you'll find a definition that for `@www` amounts to

```
\DeclareDriverSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map{
    \step[typesource=www, typetarget=online]
  }
}
```

This means that Biber converts all `@www` references to references of type `@online`. This happens even before `biblatex` gets to see these references. So as far as `biblatex` is concerned, there is no type `@www`, there is only `@online`.

Comment: I totally imagine biblatex standing there, in its own world, its own reality, its own filter bubble going: "there is no type `@www`, there is only `@online`". How sad for biblatex to not know the whole scope of the truth!

Comment: @thymaro But maybe it is better that way. `biblatex` does not need to know about the differences between `@www` and `@online` (what differences, anyway?) and can happily work on more important matters, blissfully unaware of the fact that the BibTeX world is fragmented and inconsistent at times.